# How to always run a Laravel Accessor when retrieving records

Tags: laravel, accessor

I have a `start_time` field in my table. It will be a time value like 11:30.

```
$table->time("start_time")->nullable();
```

When I save this value I use a mutator to convert the time from the user's timezone into UTC.
I then use an accessor to convert the time in UTC back to the authenticated user's timezone.

```
public function setStartTimeAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {
        //set time value to user's timezone then convert to UTC before saving to db
        $value = Carbon::parse($value, Auth::user()->timezone->location)->timezone("UTC")->format("H:i");
    }
    $this->attributes['start_time'] = $value;
}
```

```
public function getStartTimeAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value) {
        //convert UTC time to user's timezone and format
        $value = Carbon::parse($value, "UTC")->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone->location)->format("H:i");
    }
    return $value;
}
```

I know that accessors are computed and only apply the changes when accessed directly. Something like `$task->start_date`.

My question is: how can I always apply the accessor to the data from the model since I will want that time to always be converted when the record is pulled from the database before I send it back to the frontend?

Comment: If you try `$model->toArray()` for example, it'll also apply your accessor. I don't think you're going to have any issues with the above solution. You could also make a [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts), if you're going to be doing this a lot for other fields as well.

Comment: Would this work if I were to access the model via a relationship as well? Say something like `$shift->tasks`

Comment: Yes, have you tried? As long as you're working with the model it'll use the accessor  for you.

Comment: I've created a custom cast which handles the timezone conversion (since I will use it on multiple fields, thanks for that). I see what you mean by using `toArray();`. I also see now that Laravel automatically calls the accessors when I return a response as `response()->json(["task" => $task])`. So for displaying the data it's perfect, but it would be nice if the model also had the converted time immediately after retrieving the record instead of having to call `toArray()` when working with the model to get the accessor to update the field. Is anything like that possible?

Comment: What's your usecase that doesn't work at the moment? When you call `$task->start_time` or `$task->getAttribute('start_time')` it's been converted for you. I don't see what your current issue is.

Comment: To be honest, the main issue is resolved. I just needed it to display correctly when returning to the user which it does. What I want is a 'nice to have'. I wanted the record to be returned with the updated time immediately. Like `Task::find(1);` should return the record with converted value. So that when debugging I can see in the model record the converted time instead of it showing the time as saved in the DB.  So the point was the coder can easily see the converted time when pulling from DB instead of having to access the attribute directly first for it to update. It's fine if not possible